# Is it possible to create a wordpress database with php code?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

Just curious . Is it some how possible to create a database with php code?
I am having only having access to public_html folder and i want to make a wordpress installation. Is there any method to make it work?

---

I have no cpanel access and SSH access.

Thanks

Comment: Usually shared hosting providers allow the same FTP `username`, `IP`, `password` for database server as well. Upload a [DB admin script like Adminer](https://www.adminer.org) or PHPMyAdmin to public_html & then try to access the database using the same FTP credentials. If it works, then create the database from there and provide the info. to `wp-config.php` to start WordPress installation.

Comment: Tried it didn't work out

Comment: Well, ask the hosting support about DB info. :) ... unless you use a different server for database, you'll have to have some sort of database access. There is no alternative. If they don't want to give full access of database server to you, then at least ask them to create a specific user/pass with only access to one database for WordPress installation. Also, having database to another server is slow unless both the server belongs to the same local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know if you go to **wordpress.org**, you can download the latest version of Wordpress. You can unzip this, and upload those files to get started.

However, WordPress requires a MySQL database. So you will need access to a database before you can install Wordpress. This isn't something you can do over FTP.

If you already have the database information, then yes it's possible. But creating the database like that is not possible.

---

On a second thought, you may want to try to host WordPress database on another server, which won't ok for your clients since they will depend on that other server to function.

As long as the MySQL server allows the database to be accessed by external servers. When you set up WP, instead of "localhost", you'll put in the SQL server.

Instead of "localhost" (in the `wp-config.php`) you will put the IP address of the server and then the config.php will connect

```
// wp-config.php

define ( 'DB_NAME', 'yourdbname' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'yourusername' );
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'yourpassword' );
define ( 'DB_HOST', '111.222.0.1' ); // IP address of the server where MySQL is running 

// make sure MySQL server will listen to the request from your WP server IP !
```

[Host WP DB in other server.](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/can-i-host-wordpress-database-in-an-other-server.2702115/)

Comment: Hello, Thank you . Planning  to try this on. Will it slow down the website?

Comment: Well, it depends on the server (location and kind of server) that is hosting the DB and the size of the DB, ideally, you want them to both (files and DB) to be on the same server but it should work ok.

Comment: Hi,i tried it but getting this error : Error establishing a database connection- this is what i have tried. in godaddy i created a fresh installation of wordpress (domain is different).  and edited the database to update the url and edited the wp-config file as per the above answer. I am having a shared hosting.  Not sure where it went wrong

Comment: Check this (https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/Can-t-access-MySQL-database-remotely/td-p/69516) and this (https://uk.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978).

Comment: Thank you .i think this is the only possible solution when there is no SSH and cpanel access.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can create database with php code, an easier way to setup wordpress would be to use wp-cli and mysql commands. This [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/install/) gives detailed tutorial on the same.

Comment: Hello, thanks. Will it be possible to explain a littlebit more? Doesn't cli access require cpanel access?

Comment: Wordpress cli require SSH access. so i think this is also not going to work

Answer (score 0):

If the database and  database user do not already exist, your only chance is to access the Linux shell, which you might be able to do via PHP, depending on the hosts security settings.

The PHP command is `shell_exec()`

*IF* you have the rights to do this, then you have to send the right series of commands to:

1) Create the database

2) Create the database user (with password)

3) Grant access of the database user to the database

They have done something similar here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470753/create-mysql-database-and-user-in-bash-script

However, you won't have root access, and you don't even have cPanel account access, so it may not be possible.

Comment: Usually most of the hosting providers keeps it disabled initially and requires cpanel to enable them

Comment: Yes, but he wanted to know if it were possible.  And the answer is yes, *IF*